# How to exclude specific data from SOLR result?

Tags: solr

I am debutante in **SOLR** and I have following indexed data in solr:

```
Code       Status         Timestamp
8fdd04e7   temporary      2018-25-09 21:07:10PM
8fdd04e7   temporary      2018-25-09 21:17:20PM
8fdd04e7   temporary      2018-25-09 21:20:40PM
8fdd04e7   success        2018-25-09 21:27:30PM
32c313e8   temporary      2018-25-09 22:31:30PM
f663e6bc   temporary      2018-25-09 23:35:20PM
f663e6bc   failure        2018-25-09 21:35:50PM
d3fe29e7   temporary      2018-25-09 21:37:20PM
```

Here, I am looking for the those codes which have never been *success* or *failure*. What I'm looking for is:

```
Code       Status         Timestamp
32c313e8   temporary      2018-25-09 22:31:30PM
d3fe29e7   temporary      2018-25-09 21:37:20PM
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter query. 
send a request to solr with fq parameter.

ex : `http://localhost:8983/solr/CORE_NAME/select?q=*:*`
you get all the documents in solr

`Code       Status
8fdd04e7   temporary
8fdd04e7   temporary
8fdd04e7   temporary
8fdd04e7   success
32c313e8   temporary
f663e6bc   temporary
f663e6bc   failure
d3fe29e7   temporary`

In the above query `q=*:*` returns all indexed documents(* - matches all doc's).

We can filter results/doc's to get only documents which has status:temporary by using filterquery param (`fq`)

ex : `http://localhost:8983/solr/CORE_NAME/select?q=*:*&fq=status:temporary`

`Code       Status
8fdd04e7   temporary
8fdd04e7   temporary
8fdd04e7   temporary
32c313e8   temporary
f663e6bc   temporary
d3fe29e7   temporary`

**Updated.**

The below query will make to filter out results which has status value either success or failure

`http://localhost:8983/solr/CORE_NAME/select?q=*:*&fq=-status:failure&fq=-status:success`

Hope this helps,
Vinod

Comment: Your last query will retrieve more rows than what you've shown - he wants to get the unique `Codes` that never have had a value of `success` or `failure`. Your example will return `f663e6bc` and `8fdd04e7` as well, and not just the two he wants.

Comment: @MatsLindh thanks, my bad I thought it's just about filtering with status:temporary. I guess adding fq=-status: success&fq=-status: failure will work. correct me if am wrong.

Comment: As long as they're indexed as separate documents, that will just give the same rows. It won't give unique ids satisfying the requirement. The easy option I can see is indexing each unique Code as a document, and with a Status field as a multi-valued field. In that case your query would work, but it requires changing the index structure first. It can probably be solved with a streaming expression as well.

Comment: Thanks Vinod, but I have tried with this before I post which only considers records having status _temporary_. Logically, I don't have to consider those codes which has gone _success_ or _failure_.

Comment: I have tried with `group=true&group.field=code` and applied sorting as well like `code asc, timestamp desc` so that I will get the latest one. How will I exclude that group if it's first record having status _success_ or _failure_. @MatsLindh or @vinod